# Как запустить программу используя C# Net?

Tags: xaml, c#

Нужно сделать так, чтобы приложение запустило программу при нажатии кнопки. Само приложение на WPF, код на C#.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно добавить в обработчик нажатия на кнопку вызов внешней программы, например, так:

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="Run" Click="RunButton_Click" />
```

C#:

```
private void RunButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("Notepad.exe");
}
```

Comment: Не выходит, программа сама WPF.

Comment: Не имеет значения, на основе чего сделано приложение. Более подробный пример: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx

Comment: А почему тогда не выходит? Process как я знаю везде в C# есть. А у меня почему-то не получается добавить.

Comment: Потому что using System.Diagnostics;